# How do I turn off Galaxy Tab completely?

Tags: power-on, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I received a Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 (GT-P3113) for the holidays. I recently deduced that since I can install apps from Google Play on my PC to the Tab when it's off, that it's not really turned off. How do I turn it off completely?

Comment: I think your deduction is flawed. The fact that you can install an app from the Play Store website when it's off doesn't prove that the tablet is still on. It queues up the install and then sends it the next time you turn it on, just like the way phones receive text messages (how would you feel if any text you got while your phone was off was simply *lost forever*?). So aside from that, are there any indications that it's **not** actually powering off?

Comment: Another example would be email. People can still send you emails if your computer is turned off - they don't get a message that says "Sorry, the recipient's PC is powered down, try again later". The server just holds them and then sends them over to the PC the next time you turn it on (and open your email client or what have you).

Comment: I turn it off, go to my PC & install an app through Google play. I hear the Tab signal that an app & icon have been installed. I turn the Tab on & the app is already setup. Another indication that the Tab isn't completely off is that its wifi connection is constantly active. There's no start up connecting to my router as in a PC when turned on. I read in some forum that holding the power button in the off position for 30 seconds (as opposed to just pushing & releasing as I do normally) turns it completely off. I only read that once & don't know if it's accurate. It was a different issue.

Comment: How are you turning it off then? With the "Power Off" menu item (or similar) after holding down the power button briefly? If you're immediately getting the install notification then you're right, it sounds like it's not actually powered off.

Comment: Figured it out. Eldarerathis, you hit the nail on the head. What I thought was turning it off was apparently just putting it to sleep (same condition as when it times out from no action)? I just tried holding the power button & then got the Power Off menu which is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Eldarerathis, you hit the nail on the head. What I thought was turning it off was apparently just putting it to sleep (same condition as when it times out from no action)? I just tried holding the power button & then got the Power Off menu which is what I'm looking for.